# Home directory locked after login, content replaced by “Access-Your-Private-Data.desktop”

Tags: login, home-directory, ecryptfs

I installed Ubuntu on my system and I chose to encrypt my home directory after the install, with the following command:

```
ecryptfs-migrate-home -u mylogin
```

It worked a couple of times perfectly : I entered my password on the login screen and my home directory was **decrypted automatically**.

I now have a problem: my home directory is **locked after about one minute** and it contains only two files:

```
$ ll
lrwxrwxrwx 1 mylogin mylogin 56 sept. 24 15:26 Access-Your-Private-Data.desktop -> /usr/share/ecryptfs-utils/ecryptfs-mount-private.desktop*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 mylogin mylogin 52 sept. 24 15:26 README.txt -> /usr/share/ecryptfs-utils/ecryptfs-mount-private.txt
```

Here is the content of the files:

`Access-Your-Private-Data.desktop`:

```
[Desktop Entry]
_Name=Access Your Private Data
_GenericName=Access Your Private Data
Exec=/usr/bin/ecryptfs-mount-private
Terminal=true
Type=Application
Categories=System;Security;
X-Ubuntu-Gettext-Domain=ecryptfs-utils
```

`README.txt`:

```
THIS DIRECTORY HAS BEEN UNMOUNTED TO PROTECT YOUR DATA.

From the graphical desktop, click on:
 "Access Your Private Data"

or

From the command line, run:
 ecryptfs-mount-private
```

I don't understand why the directory has been unmounted to protect my data while I logged in one minute ago.

Once I execute `Access-Your-Private-Data.desktop` and I enter my password, I can see my files again. But it makes me **enter my password twice** and it breaks many programs: Firefox can't launch, Gnome Shell lost some icons, Dropbox reports that it's installing again, etc.

---

What cause this? How can this be fixed?

I didn't find any solution anywhere. I don't use SSH to connect to my computer.

I use Ubuntu 16.04.3 with an [updated kernel](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack#Ubuntu_16.04_LTS_-_Xenial_Xerus).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a weird solution, I removed the entries in my account's `crontab`:

I had some lines like this my `crontab`:

```
@reboot sleep 60 && mkdir -p /run/shm/project1_cache /run/shm/project1_logs
@reboot sleep 60 && mkdir -p /tmp/project1-test-dev
```

In my home, I have added some symbolic links that point to these directories (I put the `cache` and `logs` directories in the RAM in order to speed up Symfony).

I moved these commands to a script launched with Gnome Shell's startup applications manager and it works as before.

---

I don't understand why this resolved my issue but it works for me.